# sitting up sublime as mt text editor

Tags: git, sublimetext3

so I sit up sublime 3 as my text editor 
$ git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe' -n -w"
 and I think it works but 
when I am writing 
$ git commit 
it should open right?
as its written here

> If you did configure your editor, then go ahead and make a commit
>   using the git commit command:
>
> $ git commit Remember, your editor should pop open and you should see
>   something like this:

so why its like nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

I found the command line in the github documentation is slightly different than yours :
git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files/sublime text 3/subl.exe' -w"

[Instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/#platform-windows) on github